# PHPSpreadsheet auto row height not works with LibreOffice latest version

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel, libreoffice, phpspreadsheet

I am using PHPSpreadsheet now, I am trying to get rows to auto height. It is working fine in **MSOffice** But Not work in **LibreOffice**.

> Question How to make the row auto height work in **LibreOffice** latest version. Works fine in **MSOffice**.

Autoheight

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);

foreach($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimensions() as $rowID) { 
    $rowID->setRowHeight(-1); 
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

require(APPPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php');

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;

class Events extends MX_Controller {

    public function test() {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

        $spreadsheet->getProperties()->setCreator('')
                ->setLastModifiedBy('')
                ->setTitle('')
                ->setSubject('')
                ->setDescription('');

        $spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial');
        $spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(24);

        foreach(range('A','B') as $columnID) {
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
        }

        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);

        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);

        foreach($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimensions() as $rowID) { 
            $rowID->setRowHeight(-1); 
        }

        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue("A1",'Firstname')
                ->setCellValue("B1",'Lastname')
                ->setCellValue("A2",'John')
                ->setCellValue("B2",'Doe');


        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Users Information');

        $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        /* Here there will be some code where you create $spreadsheet */

        // redirect output to client browser
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myfile.xls"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
        $writer->save('php://output');

        exit;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that [this bug in Open/LibreOffice](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=62268) has still not been fixed..... PHPExcel cannot fix that

Answer (score 7):

Try the following code

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:D4')
    ->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
```